# How to use automapper to map two classes with the same property into a third without duplicating code?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes:

```
public class Dog {
     public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Cat{
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

They will be mapped into:

```
public class Animal {
    public string AnimalName {get;set;}
}
```

What is the recommended way of using Automapper to create these mappings?

```
CreateMap<Dog, Animal>.ForMember(p => p.AnimalName, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Name));

CreateMap<Cat, Animal>.ForMember(p => p.AnimalName, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Is there a better way of configuring Automapper instead of listing the same members twice, once for Dog and another for Cat?

Note: I cannot change the source mappings (Dog, Cat) and must use them as such. Hence, I'm trying to find a way of saying "use the same mapping for cat into animal as dog into animal" so I do not have to copy the members twice.

Comment: Would you be able to have both Dog and Car implement a common interface?

Comment: Not really. I cannot change anything about the source. I just want to find a way to tell Automapper to use the same config for Cat -> Animal as Dog -> Animal. Something like CreateMap<Cat, Animal>.UseLike<Dog, Animal>() or so?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother. This sort of reuse will bite you in the future since there is no types in common in your source types. Just copy and call it a day, it's fine. And just because you physically copied the text does not mean the mapping is semantically the same - it's not.